# Retrieve document from Firestore as custom object

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a document from Firestore as a custom object called `ShopModel`. When I call the `toObject` function I get the following
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByXLC.png).

How can I solve this?

**ShopStore.kt**

```
override fun getDocument(): List<ShopModel> {
        val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        firestore.firestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().build()
        val document = firestore.collection("shops").document("1")
        document.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
            val shop = documentSnapshot.toObject<ShopModel>() //toObject 
...
```

**ShopModel.kt**

```
@Parcelize
data class ShopModel (
    var uuid: String?,
    var name: String?
) : Parcelable {constructor() : this("","")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `val shop = documentSnapshot.toObject<ShopModel>()` with `val shop = documentSnapshot.toObject(ShopModel::class.java)`. That should work.

You also don't need to specify `documentSnapshot ->` and can use `it` instead. So `val shop = it.toObject(ShopModel::class.java)`

Also make sure to use Firebase-ktx instead of Firebase. There are a hand of use kotlin-extensions that will make programming easier